# VBA Macro, Formatting Excel Sheet to Sum by Index and Account

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have more formatting questions

I am looking at a transaction sheet that has Index #'s (Column C) and Account #'s (Column E). I need to total all the entries in an entire Index, and then be able to total the all the entries in an Account. I have some code I was playing with, but I cannot figure out how to total the Account entries after taking the Index's totals.

```
Sub TotalIndex()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim fRow As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer

Set oRng = Range("c4")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column
fRow = iRow
Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Range("j" & iRow).Font.Bold = True
    Range("j" & iRow).Value = "Total"
    Range("k" & iRow).Font.Bold = True
    lRow = iRow - 1
    Range("k" & iRow).Value = "=sum(k" & CStr(fRow) & ":k" & CStr(lRow) & ")"
    iRow = iRow + 1
    fRow = iRow
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub

Sub TotalAccount()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim fRow As Integer
Dim lRow As Integer

Set oRng = Range("e4")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column
fRow = iRow


Dim laRow As Long
Dim laCol As Long

    laRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

Do
'
    If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        iRow = iRow + 1
        Range("j" & iRow).Font.Bold = True
        Range("j" & iRow).Value = "Total"
        Range("k" & iRow).Font.Bold = True
        lRow = iRow - 1
        Range("k" & iRow).Value = "=sum(k" & CStr(fRow) & ":k" & CStr(lRow) & ")"
        iRow = iRow + 1
        fRow = iRow
    Else
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If

'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

I have the code split up into two functions. One that totals the Index, and then the other function is "trying" to total the accounts inside of each Index.

[image: Errors]

Any suggestions?

Comment: So as you can see there, once I hit the next index, it quits. See I know where the problem is... But I am trying to figure out how I would go about moving on to the next index... In the picture that is Biology. I know as it stands when the code encounters a cell with no stuff in it, it stops.

Comment: Why are you using a macro to do this? Excel has built in grouping/outlining capability and you can use the `Subtotal()` function to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial, it does what you want to do per Trashman's suggestion.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuGIlPopVms

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer